# Cannot use cscope key-binding on Emacs due to syntactic analysis

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, cscope

I have a problem with using cscope on Emacs.

When I pressed "C-c C-s {g,s,..}" to use cscope, the key binding is blocked by syntactic analysis from CC mode.

The message printed out like(When I press C-c C-s) :

Syntactic analysis: ((topmost-intro 6123))

I want to use original cscope keybindings... is there any solutions for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
; using cscope
(define-key global-map "\C-\\" nil)
(define-key global-map "\C-\\s" 'cscope-find-this-symbol)
(define-key global-map "\C-\\g" 'cscope-find-global-definition)
(define-key global-map "\C-\\a" 'cscope-index-file)
```

I tried to find out the solution to disable syntactic analysis shortcuts(C-c C-s) from CC mode, I couldn't find it. Instead, by using other keybindings, I could solve the problem.